# How to guess Checksum Algorithm Type?

Tags: checksum, crc

I am trying to figure out if what I have so far is correct. Just feeling that I am chasing my own tail here, but I do feel that maybe I understand it correctly.

I have this file, where it includes a checksum that is oddly short. This is a set of two files, this one and the one I copied at pastbin under. I noticed that the first file includes the checksum, however it seems that if I change any parameter or the serial number the file will than fail to load.

I am correct to assume that the software looks for some of the xml values add in a string and create the checksum, and than compares it to the checksum in the file? I am not sure how they would have been able to add the checksum in the file itself otherwise, so I guess maybe it just takes some of the values.

Second, am I correct to assume that they just truncated the checksum? I never seen one that small.

In the end I am trying to figure out how to create my own checksum calibration but at the moment I am trying to at minimum understand how it works. Far from braking it :)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <InstrumentData xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
  xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/AcquisitionEngine.Types">
  <CalibrationMode>parabolic</CalibrationMode>
  <CalibrationTemperatures 
 xmlns:d2p1="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays">
<d2p1:double>28</d2p1:double>
<d2p1:double>52</d2p1:double>
<d2p1:double>76</d2p1:double>
<d2p1:double>90</d2p1:double>
  </CalibrationTemperatures>
  <Checksum>6E23D45E</Checksum>
  <ClusterSize>1</ClusterSize>
  <HardwareVariant>Hardware_Legacy</HardwareVariant>
  <InstrumentID>undefined</InstrumentID>
  <LineFrequency>LineFrequency_50Hz</LineFrequency>
 <MaxCalibrationDeviation>0.152</MaxCalibrationDeviation>
 <SerialNo>6328ZG200015</SerialNo>
 <Version>3.2</Version>
  </InstrumentData>
```

The second file is included here https://pastebin.com/YQ1qKZ2v

Update: I have been able to find the code that generates this but I am still not getting the same hash.

```
    private string GenerateChecksum(string serialno)
    {
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        stringBuilder.Append(this.HardwareVariant);
        stringBuilder.Append(serialno);
        return HashGenerator.GetHash32AsHex(stringBuilder.ToString());
    }
```

From this line it seems to take the HadwareVariant and the serial number. 
Than it seems to take this and generate a hash32 and than add an X2 at the end of it? My background is php, but am I understand this correct?

```
  internal static class HashGenerator
{
    private static HashAlgorithm CryptographicHasher;

    static HashGenerator()
    {
        HashGenerator.CryptographicHasher = MD5.Create();
    }

    public static int GetHash32(string value)
    {
        byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(value);
        return 

   BitConverter.ToInt32(HashGenerator.CryptographicHasher.ComputeHash(bytes), 0);
    }

    public static string GetHash32AsHex(string value)
    {
        return HashGenerator.GetHash32(value).ToString("X2");
    }
}
```

Comment: It's 4 bytes, so it's probably one of the CRC32 variants. These are just 4 bytes.

Comment: Awesome thank you I was just making sure it was not just truncated. I appreciate the help.

Comment: It is not clear what data the checksum or CRC is based on. Is some or all of the data converted into some binary form where the checksum or CRC is then calculated?

Comment: @rcgldr I found more of the code that generates this. Any idea what I am missing it seems to be a fairly simple hash but I cant seem to get the same result. Or maybe it is more than I am looking at in the code. I really appreciate the help and the time you took to look at this.